# What if Azure Function is broken?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've researching on Azure functions to create a Microservice architecture. As my researches, functions are scaled automatically, and pay what you use. But, I can't find anyting about broken functions? What if my function is broken and I'm not getting any response. Is there any probability to happen for this?

Does Azure provide for functions always up? OR do I have to move azure function to Kubernetes to handle it?

Answer (score 3):

**You don't have to worry about that**. Microsoft will ensure that your functions are up and running and provide you the following **SLA**:

> For Function Apps running on Consumption Plans we guarantee that the
>   associated functions will run 99.95% of the time after trigger is
>   successfully fired.
>
> For Function Apps running on App Service Plans we guarantee that the
>   associated Functions compute will be available 99.95% of the time.

See also: [SLA for Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/functions/v1_1/)